# How to maintain the modified record on jsp

Tags: java, javascript, jsp

i have a small requirement like following.
I have one Jsp on which i am population all details of employee details.
ON jsp i have more than 100 record. To Edit the details i am not opening any pop up. User can update some field from drop down from UI.

Also i have save button on the same Jsp so that the same record can be updated.
All the records are showing on JSP row wise.

As per requirement, i have to maintain the last modified record.
e,g user has done the modification on 100th record and clink on save, so after save JSP page will show 100th record ON JSP (as highlighted or may be some other solution ).
usually if i click on save, so all the records will be shown On JSP, so user has to go to 100th record to find the modification.

is there is any way to implement this situation.

Best Regards
Arvind Porlekar

Answer (score 0):

First request: `GET /displayRecords`: shows all the records.

Now the user chooses to scroll, edit and save the 100th record, identified by the ID 3542: `POST /saveRecord`, with the parameters `recordId=3542`, `recordFoo=bar`, etc. The server saves the record, and redirects to `/displayRecords?highlightedRecord=3542#3542`.

So third request: `GET /displayRecords?highlightedRecord=3542`. The JSP regenerates the list of records, and highlights the record identified by 3542 (thanks to the value of the parameter `highlightedRecord`).

The list of records is redisplayed, and since there is #3542 at the end of the URL, the browser looks for an anchor named or identified by 3542. If found, it automatically scrolls to this location. You just need to generate such an anchor in your HTML:

```
<a id="3542"></a>
Data of the record 3542
```

Comment: Here the problem is i dont have hyperLink to edit the record. user just modify couple of fields of the row and click on save.

Comment: When they click on save, they submit a form. In this form, you have the ID of the record as a hidden field. Without it, the server can't know which record it must update. So, since you have the ID of the record, you can redirect to /displayRecords?highlightedRecord=<ID>#<ID> after the record has been saved.